# ng-Class to return from c# class with true and false values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-material

I am returning this code in MVC 5 Controller using user defined class and rendering by using @Html.raw(), the code is executing well but when I am adding

> **ng-class='{ 'DeleteBtn': true, 'DeleteBtn': false }'**

it's giving this error.

> **Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'deletebtn':' is not a valid attribute name.**

```html
StringBuilder MyCode = new StringBuilder();
MyCode.Append("<md-button class='md-raised' ng-class='{ 'DeleteBtn': true, 'DeleteBtn': false }'ng->Delete</md-button>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should no use  apostrophe(single quote) inside apostrophe(single quote) if you want so use \ before apostrophe(single quote) 
eg:- ng-class=' \'DeleteBtn\':true '

Comment: **Suraj**, I am adding this line, **ng-class='{'\'DeleteBtn\': 'true', '\'DeleteBtn\': 'false' }'** but it says **Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: {**

Comment: append '\' as \' and remove single quote from boolean type

Comment: I did not get you, can you make changes in the above line.

Comment: sorry to ask you at this time but for what reason you are defining ng-class for

Comment: i want to set initially a class for some button when they get render later on I will change it based on condition.

Comment: are you planning to delete the btn on later changes

Comment: Yes, or could be disable.

Comment: MyCode.Append("<md-button class='md-raised' ng-class=\"{ 'DeleteBtn': status  }\">Delete</md-button>");   where deleteBtn is your class name and the status is true or false , you could give your model-name in place of 'status'